# How to get all variable names and their values, without explicitly asking it in cplex (C++)?

Tags: c++, cplex

```
IloEnv env;
IloModel model(env);

makeModel(env, model); // user-defined function to make the model

IloCplex cplex(model);
cplex.solve();
IloNumArray vals(env);
IloNumVarArray var(env);
cplex.getValues(vals, var);
env.out() << "Solution vector = " << vals << std::endl;
```

It just prints `Solution vector = []`. However, if I explicitly add `cplex.getValue(x1[i][j])`, it works.

Is it possible to get all variables (or non zero variables) names and their values, without explicitly asking for it in cplex (C++)?

Edit: As requested, a sample `makeModel()` function is given below:

```
void makeModel(IloEnv &env, IloModel &model)
{
  IloNumVar y(env, -1, 100000, ILOFLOAT);
  y.setName("y_name");
  IloExpr exp0(env);
  exp0 = y;
  model.add(IloMaximize(env, exp0));

  var2d x1(env, 5);

  for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
    x1[i] = IloNumVarArray(env,3,0,IloInfinity,ILOINT); // ILOFLOAT, ILOINT, ILOBOOL  
    // IloBoolVar a(env, "a");
    std::string name = "x1"+std::to_string(i);
    x1[i].setNames(name.c_str());
  }


  for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
  {
    IloExpr exp1(env);
    for (int j=0; j<3; j++)
    {
      exp1 += 5*x1[i][j];
    }
    model.add(exp1 <= 20);
  }

  IloExpr exp2(env);
  for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
  {
    for (int j=0; j<3; j++)
    {
      exp2 += x1[i][j];
    }
  }
  exp2 -= y;
  model.add(exp2 == 0);
}
```

Here is the generated model: [Link](https://notepad.ltd/ohztmofn)

Comment: My guess is that `vals` is actually empty. The `operator<<` overload for `IloNumArray`'s base class (`IloArray`) says "_This overloaded C++ operator directs output to an output stream._". Have you tried checking `vals.getSize()` to see what that outputs? Is it `0`?

Comment: Yes, it is empty. Yes, `vals.getSize()` is `0`.

Comment: Ok, then that's the explanation for why you get `Solution vector = []`

Comment: That is understandable. Is there any api to get all variables (or non zero variables) names and their values, without explicitly asking for it?

Comment: I've never seen cplex before. I just took a quick peek at the documentation. If `vals` is empty, what variable names and non-zero values do you expect to see?

Comment: Can you add the definition of `makeModel` to the question? I assume that's your own function?

Comment: Ohh, okay. Definitely, `vals` will not show any output. I want to know whether there is any workaround.

Comment: I see that you do `model.add(` _`IloExpr`_ `<= 20)` and `model.add(` _`IloExpr`_ `== 0)` but I couldn't find the `operator<=` or `operator==` overloads for `IloExpr` or an implicit conversion to something comparable with `int`. Do you mean to `add()` `bool`eans or what type do those comparisons return?

Comment: I think it is not a comparison, it is used to create represent equality constraint. I might be wrong though. See the generated model.

Comment: You could check just to be sure. Before `model.add(exp1 <= 20);` you could add  `static_assert(not std::is_same_v<bool, decltype(exp1 <= 20)>);` - If that compiles, the result is something else than `bool`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239928/discussion-between-mr-eu-and-ted-lyngmo).

Comment: I think that you need to populate your vars array with the set of variables for which you want to get the values from CPLEX. If you pass in an empty array of variables, you are not asking CPLEX to get the values of any variables. As a wider comment, most CPLEX models have many many thousands of variables (we regularly have over a million variables) so any function that returned the values for all of them would be useless in practice for almost all users.

Comment: @TimChippingtonDerrick, can you link to some examples of "populate vars array with the set of variables"? Why `IloNumVarArray var(env);` command does not populate `var` from existing `env`?

Comment: @Mr.EU For some reason I can't respond in the chat. Perhaps it has something to do with the update of the Stackexchange site they made Yesterday. Re: "_it is working fine_" - Aha, ok, then you were most probably correct in your assumption. I'm out of ideas unfortunately.

Comment: The reason that IloNumVarArray var(env) doesn't do what you seem to expect is that it wasn't written to do that. I have been a CPLEX user for 25 years and know quite a few of the developers. The above call is used to create a new empty IloNumVarArray. It simply does not access any pre-existing IloNumVars. For reference, try reading the C++ documentation, such as that avaiable online at https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/20.1.0?topic=ctju-accessing-solution-information. Or have a look at one of the many examples provided with the CPLEX installation, e.g.  ilomipex1.cpp.

Comment: @TimChippingtonDerrick, that's great. I miss understood `IloNumVarArray var(env)`. Earlier using cplex with lp files as in the example [iloqpex2.cpp](https://www.tu-chemnitz.de/mathematik/discrete/manuals/cplex/doc/getstart/html/ilocplex16.html). 

Bdw, may I ask in which field you work? I just started my career. I heard for large problems, it really takes a long time to solve. What is the time, in general, you allow to solver to solve?

Comment: That is a tough question to answer. Some of our customers have problems that we can solve in seconds, while others would take days or longer to solve. Once problems get big enough to take a long time we typically use one or more decomposition techniques like column generation or VLNS to get good-enough answers in reasonable time. What is a reasonable time depends on how it is used. For interactive what-if stuff then people can wait a minute or two. For monthly or quarterly planning problems people can wait overnight for answers as they don't need to do many runs or often